# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop' in a for loop to delete multiple rows in Dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete every rows in my dataframe which is having morethan 5 number of NaN values against my 'Station Id'. I have obtained the Index number of rows which has morethan 5 NaN values by using 'for' loop. I stored every index number of rows in a 1D list. Then I am trying to delete rows according to index number one by one by implimenting another 'for' loop as shown below,

my dataframe name is = df_data_3   ###(164040 rows × 12 columns)

null_rows_index = [list of number of indexes] ### 261 number, that means 261 rows which has morethan 5 NaN values

```
j = 0
for j in range(len(null_rows_index)):
    df_data_3 = df_data_3.drop(index=[null_rows_index[j]], inplace = True)
```

but this shows an error while running as below,

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

How would I drop the multiple rows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `inplace`, as you have, the operation occurs in place (no surprise), and the function returns `None`.  So, you need:

```
    df_data_3.drop(index=[null_rows_index[j]], inplace = True)
```

The documentation makes this clear, and should have been your first stop.

Comment: do you mean, I should do remove the variable 'df_data_3' in a for loop??? if yes, I removed and checked again but got the same error. and the same syntax I have used earlier which I already showed in the question.

Comment: No, that's not at all what I said.  I showed you exactly what to do.  If you had cut-and-pasted my line, it would work.  Remove `df_data_3 =` from your line.  When you pass `inplace = True`, `.drop` modifies the list in memory.  It doesn't return anything.